# Python pexpect regex match is encased in b' '

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pexpect

I'm new to Python and to pexpect, but not to TCL expect. I have a super simple script that connects to a Cisco router via SSH and queries the arp table for a mac address.  I want to retrieve the corresponding IP address. Here are the lines of interest:

```
branchConnection.sendline('sh ip arp | i 00c0.b7')
time.sleep(1)
branchConnection.expect('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
print(str(branchConnection.match.group(0)))
```

It prints b'10.198.7.10'

When I look at the pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object it shows:

```
buffer (last 100 chars): b'             2   00c0.b790.b8c6  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0.100\r\nRTR-01#'
before (last 100 chars): b'sh ip arp | i 00c0.b7\r\nInternet  '
after: b'10.198.7.10'
```

Everything is encased in b' '

I'm assuming this is normal?  Can someone please explain what is going on?  I'm having trouble finding anything that explains what this means.  How can I get pexpect to just return the IP address without b''?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal   it means it is a byte string.

Comment: `group(0)` is the entire match. you can have a try of `group(1)` to see the difference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` means bytes.  If you need a string out of it you can use `decode`.  You will need to know what encoding it is using, but if you don't know, you can try `utf-8` which is pretty common

```
print(branchConnection.match.group(0).decode("utf-8"))


>>> b'10.198.7.10'.decode("utf-8")
'10.198.7.10'
```